# Punctuation removal effect on n gram detection for keyword generation

Tags: nlp

I'm building ngrams after removing punctuation and lemmatization. The algorithm is to detect keywords in large bodies of text.

I have concerns that 2 documents

> The child played with the red ball.

And

> The sign was red. Balls are the toys of children.

would both contain "red ball". Are there best practices here? Ideally I would not want the second document to have the same value of "red ball" as the second.

Answer (score 1):

The n-gram model is often built after segmenting into words *and sentences*. If the data is segmented by sentence it's easy to avoid any overlap between sentences: one can simply extract n-grams sentence by sentence independently. In case it's more convenient to extract all the n-grams at once, padding can be used to mark the beginning/end of sentences like this:

> The sign was red #SENT# Balls are the toys of children #SENT#

Dealing with other punctuation signs which don't mark the end of a sentence can be a bit more tricky, especially if you want to keep the possibility of a keyword which spans over some punctuation signs (for instance in "red-handed" or "tl;dr").